# wait in separate thread without blocking main eventloop, async python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a problem at work where I have to wait for 10 seconds when InstrInstallSucceeded event comes in, without blocking the main thread, I should wait for InstrInstallFailed to appear, so in other words 'ToolOn', 'ToolOn', 'ToolOn' should appear without any wait.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
import time
FLAG = True



async def sleep_loop(t, event):
    global FLAG
    print(event)
    if event == 'InstrInstallSucceeded':
        # spwan a seperate thread here such that 
        # toolon events are not blocked by the sleep
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        FLAG = True
    if event == 'InstrInstallFailed':
        # and I want to update the FLAG whenever I see event == 'InstrInstallFailed'
        FLAG = False



async def keep_print():
    print(f'Beginning FLAG:: {FLAG}')
    while FLAG:
        pass
    print(f'End FLAG:: {FLAG}')



def start_loop(loop, t):
    print("in start loop")
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    for i in ['InstrInstallSucceeded', 'ToolOn','ToolOn', 'ToolOn', 'InstrInstallFailed']:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))
        loop.run_until_complete(sleep_loop(t, i))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(new_loop,10))
t.start()
coro = keep_print()
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

output

```
in start loop
Beginning FLAG:: True
Executing <Task pending coro=<sleep() running at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:482> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x1043f2be8>()] created at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:284> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:185] created at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:452> took 0.118 seconds
InstrInstallSucceeded
ToolOn
ToolOn
ToolOn
InstrInstallFailed
End FLAG:: False
Executing <Task finished coro=<keep_print() done, defined at fut.py:21> result=None created at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py:452> took 15.756 seconds
```

EDIT: using python 3.6.7

```
import asyncio

async def dispatch_event(event, alert):
    print(event)
    if event == 'InstrInstallSucceeded':
        # spawn a coroutine if you need something done in parallel
        #asyncio.create_task(xxx())
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    if event == 'InstrInstallFailed':
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)

    # alert the watcher(s) of the event that was dispatched
    alert.last_event = event
    alert.set()

async def keep_print(alert):
    while True:
        print(f'Beginning FLAG:: {alert.last_event}')
        await alert.wait()
        alert.clear()
        print(f'End FLAG:: {alert.last_event}')

async def main():
    alert = asyncio.Event()
    alert.last_event = None
    # spawn keep_print in the "background"
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = loop.create_task(keep_print(alert))
    for i in ['InstrInstallSucceeded', 'ToolOn','ToolOn', 'ToolOn', 'InstrInstallFailed']:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await dispatch_event(i, alert)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    t.cancel()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

edit as suggested by @user418.....

```
async def dispatch_event(event,alert):

    alert.last_event = event
    alert.set()

    print(event)
    if event == 'InstrInstallSucceeded':
        # spawn a coroutine if you need something done in parallel
        #asyncio.create_task(xxx())
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    if event == 'InstrInstallFailed':
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)
    # alert the watcher(s) of the event that was dispatched
```

Comment: I want to contend the downvote, I would like to know why my question was downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads and asyncio don't go together, except in specific circumstances (e.g. the implementation of [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)). Instead of spawning new threads, spawn new coroutines.

For example:

```
import asyncio

async def dispatch_event(event, alert):
    print(event)
    if event == 'InstrInstallSucceeded':
        # spawn a coroutine if you need something done in parallel
        #asyncio.create_task(xxx())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if event == 'InstrInstallFailed':
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)

    # alert the watcher(s) of the event that was dispatched
    alert.last_event = event
    alert.set()

async def keep_print(alert):
    while True:
        print(f'Beginning FLAG:: {alert.last_event}')
        await alert.wait()
        alert.clear()
        print(f'End FLAG:: {alert.last_event}')

async def main():
    alert = asyncio.Event()
    alert.last_event = None
    # spawn keep_print in the "background"
    t = asyncio.create_task(keep_print(alert))
    for i in ['InstrInstallSucceeded', 'ToolOn','ToolOn', 'ToolOn', 'InstrInstallFailed']:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await dispatch_event(i, alert)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    t.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: ok this does not work for me as I increased time to 10 seconds for `await asyncio.sleep(10)` in dispatch_event at condition `if event == 'InstrInstallSucceeded':` it seems to wait there for 10 seconds, and the continue. also I am using python 3.6.7 so I have to made certain modifications as well

Comment: ok so if I create a new event loop I am able to make the wait out in separate loop, but I have a new problem with my new code, which is over here https://pastebin.com/ade9mYSf

TLDR;
what I want to do is to set  FLAG to False when the the time runs out in the new_event_loop

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan You can rather move the setting of the alert to the beginning of the `dispatch_event()`. Asyncio is single-threaded, you simply don't need a separate thread and event loop.

Comment: from what I understood I tried your suggestion as requested @user481....., it' in my edit, but that did not help me much. please take a look

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan Have you tried using `asyncio.create_task()` as indicated in the comment?

Comment: I did not, did you mean here, ` #asyncio.create_task(xxx())` ?

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan Yes. By default the code emulates the code you've shown. But it is easy to make it more async by moving the operation (in this case `await asyncio.sleep(10)`) to a separate `async def xxx`. Inside the `if` you can just call `asyncio.create_task(xxx())`, which will execute `xxx()` "in the background".